# how to display I/O file on shell

Tags: linux, unix, shell, chmod

I am writing shell script and I need to display my output at the same time however it doesn't work with `2> somefile.txt` and if I do `| tee -a somefilel` it will not overwrite which I need to . <>

SO, i came up with ... `> newfile.txt | cat newfile.txt` , however doesn't work for a newfile and need to do chmod, but I have to run my script twice in order to get it work... so i need something more efficient than  `> newfile.txt | chmod 755 newfile.txt |cat newfile.txt`...

Basically I need a shell script I need to display my output at the same time is recording to a file without overwriting, if the file was already exist ...

I hope it make sense :) Thank you

Comment: Also asked on [unix&linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/79638/4667) -- please stick to one forum please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the `-a` from `tee` will make it overwrite instead of append.

Comment: yes, it did work. so easy :)